# Proper Artifactory repo structure for a Grails plugin?

Tags: grails, repository, grails-plugin, artifactory

I have a Grails (2.3.6) plugin (`grails-myplugin`) that needs to be used by my Grails app (`myapp`). Inside `MyPluginPlugin.groovy`, I have:

```
def version = "0.1.0"
```

After running `package-plugin` on the plugin, I'm left with `grails-myplugin-0.1-0.zip`.

I have an Artifactory server located at:

```
http://myartifactory01/artifactory
```

Inside this Artifactory instance is a repo called `myorg-releases`.

Inside `myapp`'s `BuildConfig.groovy` I need to specify the plugin as a, well, plugin:

```
plugins {
    compile:    "???"
}
```

My questions:

1. What does my `compile` closure (inside `BuildConfig.groovy`) need to be to pull the plugin in from Artifactory?
2. What does the repository path need to be for the plugin inside Artifactory? Something like: `http://myartifactory01/artifactory/simple/myorg-releases/???`? Let's pretend that in a normal Maven/Ivy situation, our `organization` is `myorg`, the name of the `module` is either `grails-myplguin` or just `myplugin` (whatever convention states), and the current `revision` is `0.1.0`.
3. How do I handle versioning of the plugin? Is it standard practice to just increase the `version` (inside `MyPluginPlugin.groovy`), then run `package-plugin` and publish the new version to Artifactory? Or is there a better/more preferred way?

Comment: I think you must start from the `repositories` section in the `BuildConfig.groovy` and to it `mavenRepo "http://myartifactory01/artifactory/"` or something similar. After that you may use your plugin in the `dependencies` section.
Something like `compile "myorg-releases:grails-myplugin:0.1.0"`.

Comment: Additionally, you may import your plugin (especially if sources are located near the main project) as `grails.plugin.location.'myplugin' = "../.../grails-myplugin/"`

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I do it with a standard Artifactory installation.

Edit: For question number 3 you can either bump up the version number in the plugin descriptor, or if making minor changes, you can republish it using the same version number (`--allow-overwrite`)  and delete myApp's target directory, which will force a new plugin installation.

/path/to/myPlugin/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.project.dependency.distribution = {
    remoteRepository(id: "localPluginReleases", url: "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-release-local/")
    remoteRepository(id: "localPluginSnapshots", url: "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-snapshot-local/")
}
```

Shell:

```
cd /path/to/myPlugin
grails clean
grails compile
grails publish-plugin --allow-overwrite --noScm --repository=localPluginReleases
```

/path/to/myApp/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy:

```
repositories {
    mavenRepo "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-snapshot-local/"
    mavenRepo "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-release-local/"
}

plugins {
    compile ":myplugin:0.1"
}
```